# Custom query vars empty

Tags: query-string

I have added to my child theme functions.php:

```
function mychildtheme_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'papers';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'mychildtheme_register_query_vars' );
```

When I try to query the var in another page

```
echo (get_query_var( $papers, $default='test' ));
```

the result is an empty string ('test' gets echoed), even if:

```
 global $wp_query;
 var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

shows the vars and their values.

Any hints ? thanks

Comment: Please show the code where you "query the var in another page". And explaining what you're trying to achieve will also help alot understanding your problem

Comment: Very silly mistake on my part, sorry: I was trying to access a non-existing papers variable instead of 'papers' query var